# Suppress duplicates, even on subsequent pages

Tags: crystal-reports

My Details section has two fields, `pallet` (string) and `qtyOnHand` (int).

The Details section is suppressed with `pallet = previous(pallet)` such that `qtyOnHand` will not repeat for a given pallet. This works fine for the current page.

A pallet's `qtyOnHand` will repeat again starting *on the next page* and restarts the suppression formula. I now get more of the `qtyOnHand` because of this. How can I suppress these values such that they will continue to be suppressed on subsequent pages too?

Answer (score 1):

Use Groups.

Group by `pallet`, then `qtyOnHand`. Instead of using the Details section, put the fields you want to display into the `qtyOnHand` Group Footer. Suppress all these new sections except for `qtyOnHand`'s Group Footer. (Suppress Details too - You don't need it where you're going.)

This will display every unique `qtyOnHand` that appears for a single `pallet` without repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've found on this site, to not repeat the value even after the next page without the need of checking the "Suppress if Duplicated" checkbox.

```
BooleanVar DuplicateISTrue := not(onfirstrecord) and previous({MyField}) = {MyField};

if DuplicateISTrue = false then  {MyField}
```